# There has to be a simple way to wordwrap the items in a combobox dropdown

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles

I've spent about a day searching for this with no luck. I just expected this to work but while the  combobox shows the text content wordwrapped when the dropdown list is not showing, the individual items in the dropdownlist are not wordwrapped. I can still change the style for all the line items, but the text does not wrap. I've played with all sorts of variations of ItemsPanelTemplate to no avail.

My existing item template is trivial.

```
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="entities:Client">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Background="LightCoral" Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

[image]

Help! Thanks

Comment: `StackPanel` allows infinite layout space. You need to set a `MaxWidth` or other similar constraint on your `TextBlock`. If you want the width of your `ComboBox`, you can use `MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}, Path=ActualWidth}"`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for and immediately fixed my problem. I appreciate your assistance. If you want to add an answer I will mark it as such.

Comment: Glad to help. Added as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments on the question:

`StackPanel` allows infinite layout space. You need to set a `MaxWidth` or other similar constraint on your `TextBlock`. If you want the width of your `ComboBox`, you can use the following:

```
MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                   AncestorType=ComboBox}, 
                   Path=ActualWidth}"
```